# Need to call scanner method read.nextInt() twice but want the same value for both

Tags: java

At the moment I'm calling the method `reader.nextInt()` twice so it's only using the `addNumber()` method for every other value rather than each one.

How do I go about fixing this issue?

I've tried using a while loop containing (true) as well as the one printed below, both encounter the same issue.

I forgot to mention, I need the programme to print the sum of all integers entered. This is to be triggered by entering the value of -1. The -1 is meant to be excluded from the sum.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberStatistics stats = new NumberStatistics();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Type numbers:");

    while (reader.nextInt() != -1)    {            
        stats.addNumber(reader.nextInt()); 
    }

    System.out.println("sum: " + stats.sum());

  }
}
```

---

```
public class NumberStatistics {

private int amountOfNumbers;
private int sum;

  public NumberStatistics() {
    amountOfNumbers = 0;
    sum = 0;
  }

  public void addNumber(int number) {
    this.amountOfNumbers++;
    this.sum += number;
  }

  public int amountOfNumbers() {
    return this.amountOfNumbers;
  }

  public int sum()    {
    return this.sum;
  }

  public double average() {

    if (this.sum() == 0) {
        return 0;
    } 
    else {
        return (double) this.sum / this.amountOfNumbers;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please post the code Here!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: @KenReid Where do you see the connection between these two questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling twice `nextInt()`, hence reading **two** nubers one after the other.

You can do what you want like this:

```
int num;
while ((num = reader.nextInt()) != -1)    {
    stats.addNumber(num);
}
```

This makes use of the fact that assignment expressions (this: `num = reader.nextInt()`) not only assigns the value to `num`, but aslo evaluate to the value being assigned, so that we can compare it with `-1`.

Comment: @DanielCutter If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: @Sweeper You should add a short explanation about what was happening IMHO, that will be more clear if someone checks it! :D Get your upvote anyway, you were faster than me :(

Comment: @Nathan I thought I explained well enough, with the `assignment expressions evaluate to the value being assigned` sentence. I don't know how I can explain better...

Comment: @Sweeper I meant precising what you mean with "assignment expression", in this case nextInt()`.

Comment: @Nathan Is this better now?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes! I proposed the addition of a sentence in the start to clarify what I felt was missing, if you want to add it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the scanner will jump to the next token for each call of `nexInt()` that's why you get the following numbers, and skip the expected one.

So don't use `nextInt()` in your `while` condition, use **[`hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt(int))** instead.

So your code would look like this:

```
int next;
while (reader.hasNextInt() && (next = reader.nextInt()) != -1){
    stats.addNumber(next);
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively just save the result inside a variable to circumvent calling `Scanner` methods for accessing the result a second time.

Comment: @Zabuza Yes maybe, but this will be less performant and may lead to NPE.

Comment: But then this will accept `-1` as a valid input, which the OP's original does not.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes well pointed out, we need to add a check condition for this too, I am editing my answer.

Comment: @Tom Yes you are right, but in the end they will result on the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `nextInt()`, the pointer in the scanner parse the int, then goes to the next element. So basically, you have :

```
pointer
   |
   |
   12345     12346    12347

while (nextInt() ...) // pointer moves to next int

           pointer
             |
             |
   12345     12346    12347

stats.addNumber(reader.nextInt()); // Now the pointer is already at the next one
```

So you are reading them two by two. You can correct this by doing:

```
int a;
while ((a = reader.nextInt()) != -1)
    stats.addNumber(a);
```

This way, the `Reader#nextInt` method is only called once.